# Using Ionic Checkbox for To-Do Ionic app

Tags: angular, checkbox, ionic-framework

I was wondering if it were possible to use a

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Item1</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

to create a to-do app where you check the ion checkbox and then press a submit button and the item is moved from the "to-do" list to a "completed list." These lists would be on the same page as so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes this is possible , try loops and objects

```
    $scope.todos = [
                {name:"item1" , completed:false},
                {name:"item2" , completed:false},
                {name:"item3" , completed:false}
               ];
```

Use ng-repeat to show the check boxes and use ng-if to show only completed and incomplete ones.

```
//show uncompleted todos
<ion-item  ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-if="!todo.completed">
  <ion-label>{{todo.name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="todo.completed"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>

//show completed todos
<ion-item  ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-if="todo.completed">
  <ion-label>{{todo.name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="todo.completed"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

This is just one way , there are many ways to do this.